# How to create a Model view Matrix in opengl es 2.0?

Tags: java, matrix, opengl-es

How can I create a Model View Matrix with the look at Methode using open gl es 2.0

Comment: Shouldn't Z be target-eye?

Comment: @MaticOblak not working eighter.. I mean the direction matters so It should not make a difference anyway...

Comment: But what is the result you are getting? The wrong order of subtraction will make you look the wrong way and cross product results will be upside-down. Next I am not sure the cross product orders are ok as well. Then you must be sure on the matrix if it is column or row major so it might be you need to transpose any of those two matrices. The multiplication order on matrices maters as well but it looks correct... Try playing around a bit with these operations.

Comment: @MaticOblak thanks for your suggestions... But even if my function is wrong the opengl function from Matrix.setLookAtM should be all right!

Comment: It should be. If you can use it you may compare results with that one. If using the  openGL look at does not work you are most likely using it wrong. The most common mistake is the wrong multiplication order. Note the standard is MVP, model by view by projection matrix. This one is meant for the view matrix.

Comment: Again, order matters in matrix multiplication! Be very careful how you do this...

Comment: @MaticOblak but that I don´t get. My version when I used the vuforia matrix worked. Now all I changed Is that instead of taking the vuforia getPose Matrix I use the Matrix  setLookat function so I haven changed any multiplications.

Comment: And what is the getPose method? The documentation I can find is idiotic. I can see no connection to the method you are using. Anyway what are you even trying to do? You say that you want to create a lookAt matrix system but I am not sure that is the case anymore. To reduce your question description: "You know one would use lookAt matrix to create kind of a static object behind your device.". Could you edit and explain your case a bit more. What is it you need to do, what is your current result, what is your expected result and what have you tried.

Comment: @MaticOblak get pose Methode gives my the model view matrix based on the relation to the target. Which I now kind of want to calculate myself

Comment: Then if you have the coordinates on where you are and what way you are looking plus the target model matrix then you create it the way you did. Simply use the lookAt procedure and have the target model matrix multiplied by it. The lookAt result should be checked by the built in matrix operation if you are creating your own. So if the result is still not what you expect then your issue is most likely somewhere else. Note that target is not the target model position but what location you are currently looking at.